# Custom UserDetailsService in spring-security

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I cant proceed further into my project because of an strange error. I am trying to implement spring-security and spring data JPA for my application, which exposes only REST api.
Now, when I am trying to implement my custom UserDetailsService class, as mentioned below, the parameter username in method loadUserByUsername is not the username I am passing as a POST request parameter, rather its the client_id parameter.
Can someone please suggest as what am I doing wrong?

```java
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private  ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;
    private String emptyPassword = "";

    public CustomUserDetailsService() {

    }

    public CustomUserDetailsService(ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService) {
        this.clientDetailsService = clientDetailsService;
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String role) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        // you can also add different roles here
        // for example, the user is also an admin of the site, then you can add
        // ROLE_ADMIN
        // so that he can view pages that are ROLE_ADMIN specific
        if (role != null && role.trim().length() > 0) {
            if (role.equals("admin")) {
                authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
            }
        }

        return authList;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        ClientDetails clientDetails = clientDetailsService
                .loadClientByClientId(username);
        String clientSecret = clientDetails.getClientSecret();
        if (clientSecret == null || clientSecret.trim().length() == 0) {
            clientSecret = emptyPassword;
        }
        return new User(username, clientSecret, clientDetails.getAuthorities());
    }
}
```

My spring-security configuration is as following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd ">


    <http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
        <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/api/**" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/api/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <http pattern="/logout" create-session="never"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <anonymous enabled="false" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" method="GET" />
        <sec:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout"
            success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" />
        <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    </http>

    <bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="com.monsor.feasthub.security.LogoutImpl">
        <property name="tokenstore" ref="tokenStore" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint" />

    <bean id="applicationContextProvder" class="com.monsor.feasthub.util.ApplicationContextProvider" />

    <bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="springsec/client" />
        <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />


    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
    </authentication-manager>


    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService" class="com.monsor.feasthub.security.CustomUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientDetails" class="com.monsor.feasthub.security.ClientDetailsServiceImpl" />

    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager" />
    </oauth:authorization-server>

    <authentication-manager id="userAuthenticationManager"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <authentication-provider ref="customUserAuthenticationProvider" />

    </authentication-manager>

    <bean id="customUserAuthenticationProvider"
        class="com.monsor.feasthub.security.CustomUserAuthenticationProvider" />


    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
        resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <bean id="tokenStore"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <bean id="tokenServices"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
        <property name="accessTokenValiditySeconds" value="300000" />
        <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
    </bean>


    <mvc:annotation-driven />   <!-- Declares explicit support for annotation-driven MVC controllers @RequestMapping, 
        @Controller -->

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <bean id="MyResource" class="com.monsor.feasthub.resources.MyResource" />

</beans>
```

Comment: Where are you posting the username and how (show us the client)?

Comment: @DaveSyer: I am passing them from google POSTMAN as http://localhost:8080/Project/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=client1&client_secret=client1&username=user1&password=user1&scope=read_myapp

Comment: If "/Project" is your server context path then that request will hit the /token endpoint (I assume you are using POST), and you have (correctly) secured it with your client details authentication manager. So what is the problem with that?

Comment: @DaveSyer : I read about UserDetailsService implementation, that if userName is passed to the method loadUserByUserName, we can load the user details from DB (or whatever..), My query is that in my case clientId is getting passed to this method not the userName being passed from POST request.

Comment: But you are authenticating a client, so the username has to be the client id. You also constructed the `UserDetailsService` to use `ClientDetailsService` so it looks like you were expecting this.

Comment: @DaveSyer : Ok, I got it now. Can you help me to figure out as how can I authenticate user credentials as well using this same approach?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73166/discussion-between-abvashis-and-dave-syer).